# Exibir formulário no meio do pinel do splitContainer?

Tags: c#

Estou usando, o seguinte código para chamar e mostrar o `form` no `panel2` do meu `splitContainer`:

```
splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Clear(); // limpa o painel2
form.TopLevel = false; // redefine lvl do form
splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(form); //add formulario ao painel 2
form.Show(); // mostra formulario
```

E a saída está sendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como alinho o `form` ao centro do meu `panel2`, ficando assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou ocupando o `panel2` todo.

Já tentei iniciar o `form` como maximizado, e ao centro alterando as propriedades do mesmo e não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, o problema seria as âncoras que estavam como `top,left`, daí não importava o que eu fazia ele sempre levava o conteúdo para o topo esquerdo.
Adicionei também um código para redimensionar meu `form` para ficar do mesmo tamanho que o `panel`

```
int altura = this.NOME-SPLIT-CONTAINER.NOME-DO-PANEL.Height;
int largura = this.NOME-SPLIT-CONTAINER.NOME-DO-PANEL.Width;
FORM.Height = altura;
FORM.Width = largura;
```